# fopen() failing to open and append file

Tags: php, macos, macos-big-sur

PT 2...This is day 4 of still not figuring out this issue.
I am brand new to learning PHP. I keep receiving an error code when trying to run my code in google chrome. As seen here:

> Warning: fopen(/var/www/html/orders.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/class_projects/ch2/processorder.php on line 68

I have changed the permission on all of my files to r/w. I have run multiple terminal commands to change permissions. I think it's obvious at this point I am making big mistake somewhere. I'm at a loss of where to even look at this point.

I tried re-running the page after this action in the terminal. I still receive the same error code. What is my next best step in approaching this issue? I'm sure it's something I'm overlooking. Thanks for taking a look.